# ssh как vpn сервер

Tags: ssh, vpn

У меня есть сервер к которому я мог подключиться только по ssh, на нем лежит сервер бд. Как мне заставить мой локальный сервер обращаться к его бд? Я могу подключиться к бд через навикат, подключиться к самому серверу через putty, но как сделать, чтобы он работал как впн сервер и можно ли?

Comment: скорее  всего можно, `google://putty ssh tunnel`, тебе нужно будет на локальной машине создать туннель от твоей машины к удаленному серверу бд, а локальному серверу бд указать локальный же адрес туннеля. схема примерно будет такая `веб-сервер->локалхост:порт->пробрасывает соединение на удаленный хост:ПортБд`. извращение, конечно

Comment: Есть ещё bitvise ssh client.https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client